# Same origin policy Cypress, two different ports

Tags: port, cypress

The website has the following url: localhost:3000/.....
I would like to call the website with the url: localhost:4000/....
with cy.visit() in a single test. Unfortunately that doesn't work because of same origin policy (I have two different ports). Could you please help me. What should I do?

I want to do that:

```
beforeach (=> {cy.visit('localhost:3000/.....')})
it(=> {cy.visit('localhost:4000')})
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is well-known in the Cypress world, it's mentioned in the documentation. If it doesn't work for your context, you should not choose Cypress in the first place. However, I'd also question the need for visiting different origins in a single test.

If you really really need to do it, then read [this part](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs#Same-origin) of Cypress documentation. It is possible:

- to visit different origins in different tests
- you can use `.request()` command to request any origin no matter what page you visited with `.visit()`

Comment: - visit different origins in different test didn't help . I just did that and showed me an error message:

Comment: .request() doesn't help me at all. I absolutely have to test the site with cy.visit.

Comment: - and I have already read this part above in cypress doc.

Comment: -   I do something like this:                      beforeEach(() => {   cy.visit('localhost:300/....')    })                                                                                  it('' , => {                                                           cy.visit('localhost: 4000/....')})

Answer (score 0):

The same-origin policy is valid because you visit it in the beforeEach. It can be easily solved if you make the visit, at the beginning of each `it` case. In my practice using beforeEach has proven hard to build and maintain because it must set up different cases and it is better for every case to be set up within it`s code.

If this doesn`t work - just separate the case into a different file and group them in a folder.

Comment: that works I know I wanted another solution. thanks a lot . I will then use this solution. thanks a lot